# How do I automatically update data in a child component?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an LWC with a parent and a child. I pass a list from the parent to the child, but I need to transform the data into multiple lists, maps, and variables.

- sending a list of time slots (wrapper class), need to build a map `[day1: {slot1, slot2}, day2 : {slot1, slot2}]` and other variables to create the user experience.
- User can select and submit the time slot, it will be passed to the parent to call an apex class, then we will refresh the original Wire and send the new time slot list to child based on new field values from SF record.

How I do call this function when loading the child component? Can I used `connectedCallback` in the child, or do I need to call a specific function?

EDIT to include code:

PARENTLWC.js

```javascript
 @wire(getServAppInfo, {servAppEncoded : '12345'})
 wiredServApp({error, data}){
     if(data){
 
             //set Service Appointment Info
             this.slotsListData = data.timeSlotList;
             this.arrStart = data.arrivalStart;
             this.arrEnd = data.arrivalEnd;
             this.workType = data.workType;
             this.appStatus = data.status;
 
             this.showPage = true;
         }else if(error){
             this.error = error;
         }
     }
```

PARENTLWC.html

```html
 <c-scheduler-web-component
      time-slot-list={slotsListData}
       onsubmit={handleSubmit}></c-scheduler-web-component>
```

CHILDLWC.js

```javascript
 @api timeSlotList;
```

I need to do the following and more with the timeSLotList (removed cuz its long):

```javascript
 timeSlotList.forEach(slotVar=>{
     if(!this.timeSlots_All.has(slotVar.dayInYear)){
         const slotVarList = [slotVar];
         this.timeSlots_All.set(slotVar.dayInYear, slotVarList);
         this.timeSlots_All_Keys.push(slotVar.dayInYear);
     } else {
         const daySlots = this.timeSlots_All.get(slotVar.dayInYear);
         daySlots.push(slotVar);
         this.timeSlots_All.set(slotVar.dayInYear, daySlots);
     }
 })
```

Comment: Or should I use this getter setter function?

https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/apiSetterGetter

Comment: or is this the better solution? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_javascript_methods

Comment: it sounds like you already have the code to call the apex method. Are you able to share that and any other relevant parts of the parent/child components with an [edit]?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Added relevant code!

Comment: @claireCrabtree which function do you want to call when loading the child? your api value in child should have the data when child is loaded

Comment: @AwaisAhamed This is where I am having trouble. I cannot load the child component until a user clicks a button. ("Reschedule"). At which point, I want to perform the function in the child on the value passed by api (which is loaded via wire in the parent on initial load.)

Just struggling to understand the best order and approach!

Comment: @AwaisAhamed is it OK to just use renderedCallback in the child? This function should be performed every time the child component is loaded.

Comment: @claireCrabtree Now since you want to invoke the logic/function in apex everytime the child is loaded. The wire function by definition is invoked everytime the child is loaded. Since you are passing api as a parameter to wire. You can make it a reactive property by prepending $. This calls the wire mehtod everytime the api value changes. Whereas the rendered callback is called everytime the child reloads any property. Connected callback could be used with imperative methods not wire.

Comment: @AwaisAhamed Sorry I explained wrong. The child function does not call apex, just transforms a list of objects into variables/maps needed. This list of objects is gotten in the parent via the wire calling apex. Child does not have any apex calls or wires.

I did try with a renderedCallback in the child and it is working! Hoping that is the right approach.

Comment: @claireCrabtree if you only need to do data transformation, then 'ConnectedCallback' or 'renderedCallback' or  will do. Depending on your user case. Basically 'ConnectedCallback' is called/invoked everytime the child is inserted into DOM and 'renderedCallback'  every time the component is pre-rendered, i.e A component is rerendered when the value of a property changes and that property is used either directly in a component template or indirectly in the getter of a property that is used in a template

Comment: ok thank you @AwaisAhamed!! Super helpful explanation. I am still learning about component rendering, etc. I really appreciate your time!